# How to write a python function as udf which returns a dictionary type

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, pyspark

I am working with pyspark. I have a spark data frame which is of the following format

```
| person_id | person_attributes
____________________________________________________________________________
| id_1    "department=Sales__title=Sales_executive__level=junior"
| id_2    "department=Engineering__title=Software Engineer__level=entry-level"
```

I have written a python function which takes the person_id and person_attributes and returns a json of the following format
`{"id_1":{"properties":[{"department":'Sales'},{"title":'Sales_executive'},{}]}}`

But I don't how to register this as a `udf` in `pyspark` with proper output type. Here is the python code

```
def create_json_from_string(pid,attribute_string):
    results = []
    attribute_map ={}
    output = {}

    # Split the attribute_string into key,value pair and store it in attribute map
    if attribute_string != '':
        attribute_string = attribute_string.split("__") # This will be a list 
        for substring in attribute_string:
            k,v = substring.split("=")
            attribute_map[str(k)] = str(v)

    for k,v in attribute_map.items():
        temp = {k:v}
        results.append(temp)

    output ={pid : {"properties": results }}
    return(output)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A column with each element as `{"id_1":{"properties":[{"department":'Sales'},{"title":'Sales_executive'},{}]}}` corresponding to each row . 

and then write that column as json

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify your function to just return map for a string, not to form the full structure.  After that, function could be applied to an individual column, not to the whole row.  Something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType,StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def struct_from_string(attribute_string):
    attribute_map ={}
    if attribute_string != '':
        attribute_string = attribute_string.split("__") # This will be a list 
        for substring in attribute_string:
            k,v = substring.split("=")
            attribute_map[str(k)] = str(v)
    return attribute_map

my_parse_string_udf = spark.udf.register("my_parse_string", struct_from_string, 
     MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
```

and then it could be used as following:

```
df2 = df.select(col("person_id"), my_parse_string_udf(col("person_attributes")))
```

Comment: Instead of registering the udf, I simply did `my_parse_string_udf 
 = F.udf(struct_from_string, returnType=MapType(StringType(), StringType()))`. What is the benefit of registering a UDF?

Comment: Benefit is that you can also use it from SQL

Answer (score 1):

In spark UDF's are considered as black box and if you want dataframe api based solution

> spark 2.4+

**Create Dataframe**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('id_1',"department=Sales__title=Sales_executive__level=junior"),('id_2',"department=Engineering__title=Software Engineer__level=entry-level")],['person_id','person_attributes'])

df.show()
+---------+--------------------+
|person_id|   person_attributes|
+---------+--------------------+
|     id_1|department=Sales_...|
|     id_2|department=Engine...|
+---------+--------------------+
```

**Convert person_attributes in map format**

```
df2 = df.select('person_id',f.map_from_arrays(f.expr('''transform(transform(split(person_attributes,'__'),x->split(x,'=')),y->y[0])'''),
         f.expr('''transform(transform(split(person_attributes,'__'),x->split(x,'=')),y->y[1])''')).alias('value'))

df2.show(2,False)

+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|person_id|value                                                                        |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id_1     |[department -> Sales, title -> Sales_executive, level -> junior]             |
|id_2     |[department -> Engineering, title -> Software Engineer, level -> entry-level]|
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**create your required structure**

```
df2.select(f.create_map('person_id',f.create_map(f.lit('properties'),'value')).alias('json')).toJSON().collect()

['{"json":{"id_1":{"properties":{"department":"Sales","title":"Sales_executive","level":"junior"}}}}',
 '{"json":{"id_2":{"properties":{"department":"Engineering","title":"Software Engineer","level":"entry-level"}}}}']
```

You can collect or use the dataframe directly, incase of collect use this

```
import json
for i in data:
    d = json.loads(i)
    print(d['json'])

{'id_1': {'properties': {'department': 'Sales', 'title': 'Sales_executive', 'level': 'junior'}}}
{'id_2': {'properties': {'department': 'Engineering', 'title': 'Software Engineer', 'level': 'entry-level'}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. The cluster/spark I work with does not have this collect_map_from_arrays function. But what you did helps me in other cases